# Joomla template that shows small sections with posts by category and a slider?

Tags: joomla

I'm searching already for a while for a nice template for my joomla site, but can't find anything. I need a template that would have on its initial page a slider that would pick automatically posts of a certain tag/category and would show small sections with a summary of each category.

Something like this:
http://www.infowars.com

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't think anything like that would be built into a template. You are better off looking for a module that does the same - it would work on any template.

I've used [GK PhotoSlide](http://tools.gavick.com/photoslide.html) before now - it's free but it doesn't generate slides automatically, you have to add images manually. (Actually I don't think you'll find an automatic one because there is no way to determine what image to show for an article.)

Have a look on the [Joomla Extensions](http://extensions.joomla.org) site for more.

Comment: "there is no way to determine what image to show for an article" Cant we define a standard picture for the post in Joomla, in the same way you do for WP?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend `http://demo.rockettheme.com/free/quasar/`  and use any of extensions from here `http://www.yootheme.com/tools/extensions`